# Tableau version of Tabular

Tags: powerbi, tableau-desktop, tabular-editor

Power BI have a great tool called tabular editor that does the calculations in SSMS that I remember, which makes it much more faster than make calculation inside Power BI. Does tableau have something similar?

I search in google and charGPT, but I had no luck with this

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

Unfortunately, Tableau has some steps to make calculations like these more accessible and faster, speaking on the UX side.
The closest feature to the tabular editor in Power BI, which you can find in Tableau Desktop, is the screen "Data Source" (you can find it on the bottom left side).